# GoogleCloudPlatform php-docs-samples delete collection does not work

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

my firebase structure is like this:
Home > messages

ProjectId

```
 |_              messages

   messages  >    sdadsdsdadsasddsda-dasdadasdadsdad
                  asdewrwergtertetrt-werrwrwttyyttyr
                  ................
                  .......
                  ....
```

i'm running this php script:

```
function delete_collection()
{
      global $projectId;
      $db = new FirestoreClient(['projectId' => $projectId, ]);
      $collectionReference = $db->collection('messages');
      $documents = $collectionReference->documents();
        foreach ($documents as $document) {
             if ($document->exists()) {
                 $document->reference()->delete();
           } 
         }
```

but the document list is empty and never go into the foreach loop.

**i really need to delete the initial colection messages**, because this is automatically create when the user send messages

thanks for your help!

Comment: I had to look up what `select` does here, never realized the PHP SDK supported selecting specific fields. Since you're trying to select all fields, can you try it without the select? So just `$documents = $collectionReference->documents();`. I don't think it will make a difference, but that was the first thing that stood out to me.

Comment: ok, i removed the "select", but still does not work